# How to remove sticky/fixed header from Weebly website containing JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, weebly

So I'm currently designing a website on Weebly. However, the theme that I'm using contains a sticky/fixed navigation menu. So whenever I scroll up or down, the nav bar always sticks to the top. I want it so that the nav bar stays in an absolute position and doesn't stay fixed to the top when scrolling.

I've tried editing the CSS and changing the position of the "header" from

`position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;` but that doesn't seem to have done anything at all. The main trouble is that my website contains JavaScript too which I believe also has some control over the position of the header. I've found certain parts of JS code which I believe have some influence over the sticky function.

```
if ($body.hasClass('header-sticky-up')) {
        base._utils.onScrollDirection({
          down: function(currentScrollTop) {
            $header
              .removeClass('is-visible')
              .toggleClass('is-sticky', (currentScrollTop > headerHeight * 2));

            base._closeAllDropdowns();
          },
          up: function() {
            $header.addClass('is-visible');
          },
```

Does anyone with a JS background have a fix to this?

Also the "header-sticky-up" relates to a function in the CSS part of the code which goes like this:

```css
 body.header-sticky-up & {
    position: fixed;

    &.is-sticky {
      .translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
      .transition(transform 0.2s ease-out);
    }

    &.is-visible {
      .translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: not a gread advice but try using !important in  `position: absolute !important;`, and check whether any other CSS there is overriding your classes

Answer (score 0):

use position:absolute!important in your styling